# How can I remotely display images on my computer?

Tags: ubuntu, audio, images, networking, remote-control

**What I Have:** A laptop booted with Ubuntu and a stationary computer dual-booted with Ubuntu and Vista, both connected through a wireless ad-hoc network.

**What I Want:** I want a way to display images in fullscreen on my stationary, using my laptop as a "remote control". I want to be able to choose another picture at any time and have my stationary computer remain in fullscreen mode at all times. Preferably, I should also be able to display just an empty (black) screen. How can I arrange for this?

**What I Have Tried:**

- I have tried simply SSH:ing into my stationary computer and opening the image files using an image viewer, but all of the ones that I have tried (Eye of Gnome, Mirage, Gwenview, and others) open a new window for every new image. I don't know how to force them into using a single instance.
- I have tried using the VLC remote control command line interface, but apart from seeming somewhat unreliable (exiting with segmentation faults at one point), it also displays some images with a green border and forces me to `pause` playback in order for the image to remain on screen.

**Bonus Question:** In my final setup, I also need to play music through my stationary computer's speaker and have the ability to switch to another track at any point, like with the images. Preferably, I would like to control the images and the audio through the same interface. How can I best achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After hours of frustration, I finally found two tools that can do what I want: [GQview](http://gqview.sourceforge.net/) and [MPlayer](http://www.mplayerhq.hu/).

GQview [can be controlled interactively](http://gqview.sourceforge.net/docs/11_1_command_line.html) through the command line, [as can MPlayer](http://www.mplayerhq.hu/DOCS/HTML/en/commandline.html).

**Update:** GQView is now called [Geeqie View](http://sourceforge.net/projects/geeqie/) and seems to load images faster than the old version.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using `xv` with the `-root` option which basically sets the image as wallpaper.  There's probably a command-line option in the other image viewers that would perform a similar function.

Comment: Does it support changing images directly without creating a new instance of the program? The installation process for XV seems pretty complicated so I'd rather know what it can do before I try to get it working.

Comment: It's been a long time since I used it, circa 1996, so I don't even know if it still works...  I believe that it set the image on the root console and then exited.  So each time you changed the image, you would start the program and then exit.

Comment: Found via [ http://forums.whirlpool.net.au/archive/613515 ], you might want to try the command (assuming Gnomoe): gconftool-2 --set --type string /desktop/gnome/background/picture_­filename my_new_bg.jpg